# is an advanced Python completion possible with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to have a completion in Sublime Text 3, for Python code documents, that would:

1. Complete the actual object method and other properties (like e.g.: `os.path.isd` → `os.path.isdir` *without* any previous occurence of the word `isdir` in the document).
2. Complete the general set of all document's words with a second, lower priority ↔ i.e.: have them listed them after the actual methods.
3. I would also like to see ST letting the words appearing *nearier* from the completion point to appear higher in the completion popup window.
4. Basically, I would like to have a completion resembling the Vim's `CoC` for C++ in its general features.

Is this possible? If yes, then what should be done to configure Sublime Text 3 for such coimpletion?

The behavior after installing the Python Completions package is far from perfect — all it does is apparently changing the priorities of the basic completion sources (after adding some that i didn't identify), so that it's *worse* than the shipped original' completion.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) package (not at all related to the Anaconda Python distribution) does most of what you're looking for. You may also want to take a look at the [`LSP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) package as well.

Comment: I'm interested in the LSP package however installing it and then enabling the `pyls` language server doesn't yield a working setup – completion is the default, nor do any of the LSP keybindings work…

Comment: @psprint I'm actually encountering the same issue. Not only is `pyls` not working, my formerly working `clangd` setup for C isn't working anymore. Check out the Sublime LSP Discord channel [here](https://discord.com/channels/280102180189634562/645268178397560865) and you can talk to the devs and some power users.